# In Python why does a 'False' string, via Input function is considered as Truthy instead of Falsy?

Tags: python

In Python, why a 'False' input entry via input function is being considered as a Truthy?

For e.g. in the below code block,

```
a_value = input('Enter the a value :')
b_value = input('Enter the b value :')
print('a_value =', bool(a_value))
print('b_value =', bool(b_value))
```

and the Output is,

```
Enter the a value :False
Enter the b value :False
a_value = True
b_value = True
```

as far as I understood, 'False' string is considered as 'Falsy'. Can someone explain why, please?

Comment: Because it's non-empty. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as far as I understood, 'False' string is considered as 'Falsy'

No, the only falsy string is `''`.

```
>>> bool('')
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Any non-empty string is considered truthy regardless of the contents; therefore, `'False'` is a truthy value as observed.